# Acces data from non-direct related model

Tags: cakephp

I have a big question, i have 3 days now trying to find the solution. I explain

I have 3 models: `Comprobantes`, `Receptores` and `Puestos`.

Comprobantes have a field called `receptor_id` which gives you the receptor and
Receptor have a field call `puesto_id` which gives you the puesto, something like

Comprobantes access to Receptores and Receptores access to Puestos, the thing now is that I had made a relation to show the field puesto from Puestos of my Receptor in the Comprobantes Model the only problem i had is that only the id is shown and i want to show the field "puesto" from Puesto not the "id" from Puesto.

edit: This is the code but Comprobantes dont have a direct relation with Puestos

```
class Puesto
{

    var $hasMany = array(
        'Receptor' => array(
            'className' => 'Receptor', 
            'foreignKey' => 'puesto_id'
        )
    );

}

class Receptor
{

    var $belongsTo = array(
        'Emisor' => array(
            'className' => 'Emisor', 
            'foreignKey' => 'emisor_id'
        ), 
        'Puesto' => array(
            'className' => 'Puesto', 
            'foreignKey' => 'puesto_id'
        )
    );
}
```

Comment: First of all, check the names of your Models it is not compatible with CakePHP conventions. Model name should be singular of the database table name.

Comment: my models are in singular, sorry i had bad written the names here but in cakephp are well written

Comment: Could I understand that Comprobantes and Puestos table are have Many to Many relationship and Receptores is the joining table?

Comment: class Puesto {
  var $hasMany = array(
        'Receptor' => array(
            'className' => 'Receptor',
            'foreignKey' => 'puesto_id')
    );  } class Receptor{var $belongsTo = array(
        'Emisor' => array(
            'className'    => 'Emisor',
            'foreignKey'    => 'emisor_id'),
        'Puesto'=>array(
            'className'=>'Puesto',
            'foreignKey'=>'puesto_id'
            )
    );}                                 This is the code but Comprobantes dont have a direct relation with Puestos

Comment: Check the documentation about [HABTM](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#hasandbelongstomany-habtm) and [Has Many Through](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#hasmany-through-the-join-model) There is no solution for your issue without clear understand for those. Your tables structure talks about HABTM or Has many through.

Comment: Ok thanks i will check it  and will let you know

Comment: Hello i checked the documentation but it doesn't fit with problem, the thing is that i want to display data of model Puesto in my model Comprobantes but is has not a direct relation, so that is the main problem i guess, only displays the id of Puesto

Comment: I also try with containable but it doesn´t work at all :/